# In an iPhone app is it smart to store user data in Core Data and then call a RESTful script as needed?

Tags: iphone, security, rest, core-data, ios5

I'm building an iPhone app and it has a registration function where the user inputs all their information.  I save that information in Core Data.  Then I write it to a DB so I can call a RESTful script against it and check their email address and password against it, validating the user.

However I was thinking should I just leave this data in Core Data.  Normally being security-minded I'd erase it and just use the RESTful script to validate.  However, what are the specific reasons why I shouldn't leave all of the user data in Core Data, check if the Core Data object still exists on login, and if it does exist use the Core Data entity to log in the user?  If the CD entity's instance doesn't exist then I'll check against the DB using the RESTful script.

Specifically, I want to know:

1. Is it dangerous to do this from a security perspective?
2. Is it dangerous to do this from a app stability perspective?
3. Is this poor coding practice according to Apple or stylistically?

What are the reasons that I should do this or that I shouldn't.  Please let me know in a clear "I would recommend this." or "I would not." and here's why as I want clarity and technical decisiveness.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing only user detail like email address and password, then you should use

**NSUserDefaults** , it is best place to store this type of information., you can also get information from it easily.